# Which canonicity is more right in a Legends question?

Tags: discussion

Per usage policy of [star-wars-legends](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-legends):

> Use this tag if your question references Legends sources and/or to indicate that answers are permitted to use Legends sources.

Where Disney canon and Legends contradict each other, which of the two is "more correct" for a question with the above tag?

**Example question**: What interactions with the rest of the galaxy did Yoda have during his exile, before Luke's arrival?

**Canon answer**: He telepathically kept in contact with Jedi survivors who have not lost their way.

**Legends answer**: Random people visited Dagobah and encountered/visited him from time to time, some aware of his true identity.

Which is the correct answer?

Generalising from the example: When interpreting a question with the [star-wars-legends](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-legends) tag, how should we tell whether it means "I am ok with the answer being canon-only, Legends-only or containing both" as opposed to "I want the answer to be Legends-only"? Even in the first interpretation, is Disney canon still considered a more correct answer when the tag is used?

Comment: Tempted to close as a dupe because I would post damn near the same exact answer as I posted on [your other question](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/8054/5184).

Comment: It's a bit similar, but that other question asks "Should I put both?" not "which would be more correct?" Normally, canon > all, but what happens if this tag is used?

Comment: Again, I'd still post almost exactly the same answer. I'd still suggest posting both if you have enough information. The only difference being that I'd upgrade the legends only answer from "meh" to "perfectly acceptable".

Comment: http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/8054/which-canon-level-should-star-wars-questions-be-answered-with-if-an-answer-exist?rq=1

Answer (score 4):

> When interpreting a question with the [star-wars-legends](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-legends) tag, how should we tell whether it means "I am ok with the answer being canon-only, Legends-only or containing both" as opposed to "I want the answer to be Legends-only"? Even in the first interpretation, is Disney canon still considered a more correct answer when the tag is used?

Unless the asker specifically says in the question text that "I want the answer to be Legends-only", we have to assume that canon vs. Legends answers are perfectly acceptable -- they can be canon-only, Legends-only, or contain both. Any of these answers are potentially worthy of upvotes. As always, canon + Legends answers are preferred (it doesn't hurt to include more information even if the asker only cares about Legends, especially for anyone else interested in the question).

I suppose we could instruct askers to include [star-wars-legends](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-legends) but *not*  [star-wars](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars) if they only want Legends answers, but this is such a rare case that I see no point in doing this. Thinking [star-wars](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars) was forgotton, an editor is likely to add it later on anyway.

Generally, canon supersedes Legends so a canon answer is usually preferred. Only the asker can determine if Legends supersedes canon for the purposes of his question, and askers already have a way of indicating the response that best answered their question: answer acceptance.

Answer (score 2):

Both are "*right*" (or rather, neither are wrong), however the consensus of opinion, as evidenced by the weight of upvotes seems to be that answers that come from works within the studio's [officially recognised canon](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/910/how-is-canonicity-of-derivative-works-determined-for-star-wars?lq=1) are more valued by the community and are generally more likely to receive an acceptance than those that are based on answers from works within the "Legends" canon.

Where you find two sources that directly diverge from each other, I'd strongly suggest you lead with the Disney canon evidence first, then highlight that a lower level canon source contradicts it. Often this can be as interesting as the answer itself.